# Hyper-V not recognized as enabled by some of my computer programs

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, wsl2, bluestacks

I wanted to try Android gaming emulators on my PC. Some of the recommended ones were Bluestacks (v4.260) and Memu (v.7.3.3), so I installed them. Bluestacks handled it fine and was able to run. Memu however said that it wont work with Hyper-V enabled and told me to repair. I searched around online and found that Memu is able to run with Hyper-V if Program Files\Microvirt\MEmuHyperv exists. I checked and it did, so I assumed repair would allow Memu to run with Hyper-V. Instead it just disabled it, but apparently in a somewhat harmful way I will soon discover. So I uninstalled it completely with Revo Uninstaller and reenable Hyper-V from the control panel. The problem is Bluestacks began to fail to recognize that Hyper-V is enabled and my ArchWSL2 instance started to crash on startup. I did reenable the necessary Windows (10 Pro) features and rebooted it. I tried reenabling it through cmd DISM and Admin Powershell. I checked Task Manager to see if virtualization was enabled. I checked services.msc and also the BIOS. All of them pointed that Hyper-V was enabled. So I decided to restore to a point that was a few hours ago, before all this emulator mess. But the problem still persists, Bluestacks won't start and Arch kept crashing. What the hell did Memu do to my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update or reinstall a fresh Windows OS. The ArchWSL network folder can be opened again and Bluestacks Hyper-V runs normally.