# Bluestacks Hyper-V Beta does not recognize Hyper-V as enabled

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v, bluestacks

The steps I took to enable Hyper-V are just like the one described [here](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045043291)

Hyper-V is enabled according to Control Panel:

[image]

Already restarted the PC.

Using the command in CMD results in this:

[image]

[Checking `services.msc` for Hyper-V](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODPVE.png).

[Virtualization is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzbZa.png).

[However, Bluestacks still considers Hyper-V to be disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKG0b.png). It also rolls back all 657 MB of installation so I have to redownload it again every time I attempt to install it.

What should I do to make Bluestacks run properly? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What other Hypervisors do you have installed other than Hyper-V?  [Why did you decide to submit two questions about the same issue?](https://superuser.com/questions/1634287/hyper-v-not-recognized-as-enabled-by-some-of-my-computer-programs)

Comment: Have you enabled Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform?  Your screenshot doesn’t show one way or another

Comment: @Ramhound they're enabled

Comment: “It also rolls back all 657 MB of installation so I have to redownload it again every time I attempt to install it.” - Avoid this by running the file in the temporary files folder.

Comment: Searched further, it's the exact same problem as https://old.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/jpq656/cant_launch_bluestacks_in_windows_version_20h2/

Answer (score 0):

Updating my Windows worked. Reinstalling might also help.

Comment: What does "Updating my Windows worked." mean?  Running "Windows Update"? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.